# error cs0103 the name does not exist in the current context

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I have my game with facebook invite integrated using unity3d. When switched to Android, everything works fine but when I switch to WebGL, I get the following error:

**error CS0103: The name `LoggedSuccefull' does not exist in the current context**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

#if FACEBOOK
    using Facebook.Unity;
#endif


public class FacebookManager : MonoBehaviour {
    private bool LoginEnable;
    public GameObject facebookButton;
    //1.3.3
    private string lastResponse = string.Empty;
    public static string userID;
    public static List<FriendData> Friends = new List<FriendData> ();
    public bool logged;

    protected string LastResponse {
    get {
            return this.lastResponse;
}

    set {
            this.lastResponse = value;
}
}

    private string status = "Ready";

    protected string Status {
    get {
            return this.status;
}

    set {
            this.status = value;
}
}


    bool loginForSharing;
    public static FacebookManager THIS;

    void Awake () {
        if (THIS == null)
            THIS = this;
else if (THIS != this)
            Destroy (gameObject);
        DontDestroyOnLoad (this);
}

    void OnEnable () {
#if PLAYG
        NetworkManager.OnLoginEvent += GetUserName;

#endif

}


    void OnLevelWasLoaded () {
        if (logged && SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().name == "game")
            LoggedSuccefull ();

}

    void OnDisable () {
#if PLAYG
        NetworkManager.OnLoginEvent -= GetUserName;

#endif
}
    #if PLAYG || GAMESPARKS
    public FriendData GetCurrentUserAsFriend () {
        //code
}
    #endif

    #region FaceBook_stuff

    #if FACEBOOK
    public void CallFBInit () {
        Debug.Log ("init facebook");
        FB.Init (OnInitComplete, OnHideUnity);

}

    private void OnInitComplete () {
        Debug.Log ("FB.Init completed: Is user logged in? " + FB.IsLoggedIn);
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {//1.3
            CallFBLogin ();
}

}

    private void OnHideUnity (bool isGameShown) {
        Debug.Log ("Is game showing? " + isGameShown);
}

    void OnGUI () {
        if (LoginEnable) {
            CallFBLogin ();
            LoginEnable = false;
        }

    }


    public void CallFBLogin () {
        Debug.Log ("login");
        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions (new List<string> () { "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" }, this.HandleResult);
        }

    public void CallFBLoginForPublish () {

        FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions (new List<string> () { "publish_actions" }, this.HandleResult);
        }

    public void CallInvite () {
        this.Status = "Logged FB.AppEvent";
        FB.Mobile.AppInvite (new Uri ("//URI Here"), callback: this.HandleResultInvite);
        // NOTE !!  create your app link here https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host
    }

    protected void HandleResultInvite (IResult result) {
        if (result == null) {
            this.LastResponse = "Null Response\n";
            Debug.Log (this.LastResponse);
            return;
        }
        // Some platforms return the empty string instead of null.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (result.Error)) {
            this.Status = "Error - Check log for details";
            this.LastResponse = "Error Response:\n" + result.Error;
            Debug.Log (result.Error);
        } else if (result.Cancelled) {
            this.Status = "Cancelled - Check log for details";
            this.LastResponse = "Cancelled Response:\n" + result.RawResult;
            Debug.Log (result.RawResult);
        } else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (result.RawResult)) {
            this.Status = "Success - Check log for details";
            this.LastResponse = "Success Response:\n" + result.RawResult;


        } else {
            this.LastResponse = "Empty Response\n";
            Debug.Log (this.LastResponse);
        }

    }

    public void CallFBLogout () { 
        FB.LogOut ();
    //code
    }

    public void Share () {
        if (!FB.IsLoggedIn) {
            //code
    }

    protected void HandleResult (IResult result) {
        if (result == null) {
            this.LastResponse = "Null Response\n";
            Debug.Log (this.LastResponse);
            return;
        }

        //     this.LastResponseTexture = null;

        // Some platforms return the empty string instead of null.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (result.Error)) {
            this.Status = "Error - Check log for details";
            this.LastResponse = "Error Response:\n" + result.Error;
            Debug.Log (result.Error);
        } else if (result.Cancelled) {
            this.Status = "Cancelled - Check log for details";
            this.LastResponse = "Cancelled Response:\n" + result.RawResult;
            Debug.Log (result.RawResult);
        } else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (result.RawResult)) {
            this.Status = "Success - Check log for details";
            this.LastResponse = "Success Response:\n" + result.RawResult;
            LoggedSuccefull ();//1.3
        } else {
            this.LastResponse = "Empty Response\n";
            Debug.Log (this.LastResponse);
        }
    }

    void LoggedSuccefull () {//1.3
        logged = true;

        facebookButton.SetActive (false);//1.3.3
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Facebook_Logged") == 0) {
            GameObject rewardPopup = Instantiate (Resources.Load ("Reward")) as GameObject;
            rewardPopup.transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<RewardIcon> ().SetIconSprite (0);
            InitScript.Instance.AddGems (10);
        }

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Facebook_Logged", 1);
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();

        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().name != "game")
            return;

        //Debug.Log(result.RawResult);
        userID = AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.UserId;
        GetPicture (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.UserId);

    }

    void GetUserName () {
        FB.API ("/me?fields=first_name", HttpMethod.GET, GettingNameCallback);
    }

    private void GettingNameCallback (IGraphResult result) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (result.Error)) {
            IDictionary dict = result.ResultDictionary as IDictionary;
            string fbname = dict ["first_name"].ToString ();

#endif

        }

    }


        void GetPicture (string id) {
            FB.API ("/" + id + "/picture", HttpMethod.GET, this.ProfilePhotoCallback);
    }

    private void ProfilePhotoCallback (IGraphResult result) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (result.Error) && result.Texture != null) {
            Sprite sprite = new Sprite ();
            sprite = Sprite.Create (result.Texture, new Rect (0, 0, 50, 50), new Vector2 (0, 0), 1f);
            InitScript.profilePic = sprite;

#endif
        }

    }



    public void SaveScores () {
        //code
    }

    public void ReadScores () {

        FB.API ("/me/objects/object", HttpMethod.GET, APICallBack);
    }

    public void GetFriendsPicture () {
        FB.API ("me/friends?fields=picture", HttpMethod.GET, RequestFriendsCallback);
    }


    private void RequestFriendsCallback (IGraphResult result) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (result.RawResult)) {
        //          Debug.Log (result.RawResult);
//code
    }

    //}
}
//print(firstGroup["id"] + " " + firstGroup["title"]);
}
//this.gamerGroupCurrentGroup = (string)firstGroup["id"];
}
}


if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (result.Error)) {
    Debug.Log (result.Error);

}
}
}

public void GetPictureByURL (string url, FriendData friend) {
        StartCoroutine (GetPictureCor (url, friend));
}

IEnumerator GetPictureCor (string url, FriendData friend) {

        Sprite sprite = new Sprite ();
WWW www = new WWW (url);
yield return www;
sprite = Sprite.Create (www.texture, new Rect (0, 0, 50, 50), new Vector2 (0, 0), 1f);
friend.picture = sprite;
//      print ("get picture for " + url);
}

public void APICallBack (IGraphResult result) {
        Debug.Log (result);
}

    #endif
    #endregion

}

public class FriendData {
    public string userID;
    public string FacebookID;
    public Sprite picture;
    public int level;
    public GameObject avatar;
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Sorry but this is not enough to help you at-all. You need to post all the code in that script that is throwing this error. All of them including the ones at the top with the `using` keyword.

Comment: @Programmer Code updated.

Comment: What directory is that script placed?

Comment: i guess it has somethng to do with preprocessors made for Android and not WebGL.